# Front USB Port of BitFenix Neos intermittantly fails in Windows 10, always works in UEFI

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

I installed my new system with these components:
[AsRock AB350M-HDV](http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/AB350M-HDV.pdf) motherboard, Ryzen 5 2400G CPU, Samsung 860 Evo SSD, [Bitfenix Neos Chassis](https://www.bitfenix.com/global/en/products/chassis/neos/).

I installed Win10 x64 from a bootable USB 2.0 stick using one front USB Port of my case. Everything worked well and I went on installing latest drivers from Asrock/AMD homepages.

After a few hours I noticed that my front USB-Ports (1x USB 3.0, 1x USB 2.0) aren't working as expected. I tested them with several devices (WLAN stick, USB stick, external HDD, ...).

Sometimes I see them in Windows Device Manager and they work correctly (can access external HDD...).

But, sometimes when I plug in a device, nothing happens. There's no change in Device Manager and also no corresponding message in the Windows Event Log. The same device consistently works on the rear mainboard USB ports.

When a device is not recognized on the front USB ports, I reboot to UEFI, and see the hardware working (e.g. external HDD), so I don't think it is a loose contact for the front USB port of my case.

I also can't imagine this is a driver problem because, ever since Win 8.1, the USB drivers are included from Microsoft.

How may I troubleshoot this further to isolate the problem?

Comment: When it happens, does it happen on both USB 3 & USB 2 front ports or just one of the two? You may like to run Live Linux for a few days just to observe if it also fails under Linux. You may like to also install a Back panel I/O USB 3 Bracket in place of the current front panel on the same header. Now check if it's stable, if yes there might have been some cable fault with the built in connectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently seen other motherboards require a driver not included in Windows, but there is no USB driver shown at the [ASRock website for your motherboard](https://www.asrock.com/MB/AMD/AB350M-HDV/index.asp#Download).

It's much more likely there's a loose connection on the cable from the front panel to the motherboard, or a defect in the cable from BitFenix, as per [Pournelle's Law](https://www.jerrypournelle.com/chaosmanor/pournelles-law/). Please consult [the manual](http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/AB350M-HDV.pdf) and recheck that connection.

Trying the suggestions from [pat2015](https://superuser.com/users/453732/pat2015) are also recommended.